Using Cauchy's estimate to show a function is constant
If $f$ is entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq |z|^{1/2}\log(1+|z|+|z|^2)$. Show that $f(z)=c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{C}$.
My approach:
Let $p\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}_r(p)\subset \mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is continuous on the closure of the disc and holomorphic on the interior, because it is entire. Now, I apply Cauchy's estimate. For $n=1$ we have the following $$|f^\prime(p)| \leq \dfrac{1}{r}\sup_{|z-p|=r}|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1}{r} \sup_{|z-p|=r}|z|^{1/2}\log(1+|z|+|z|^2)$$
since this is true for all $r>0$. I just take $r\to \infty$ and we have $f ^\prime (p)=0$. Completing the proof. I am not sure the part where I take $r$ to infinity is allowed since the sup also depends on $r$?

$$\sup\limits_{|z-p|=r}|z|^{1/2}\log(1+|z|+|z^2|)\leqslant(r+|p|)^{1/2}\log(1+r+|p|+(r+|p|)^2)=o(r)$$

We can take $p=0.$
Since $f$ is entire, the power series centered at $0$ converges everywhere.
On the boundary of the disk of radius $r,$ we have $\mid f(z)\mid\le r^{1/2}\log(1+r+r^2)=o(r),$ because $$\frac {\log(1+r+r^2)}{r^{\frac 12}}\to0.$$
So Cauchy's estimate indeed gives $f'(0)=0,$  by letting $r\to\infty. $
Similarly for all the higher order derivatives at zero, and the power series is constant.
(Actually your approach is slightly different,  but will show $f'\equiv 0,$ which also works. )
So your concern is allayed and $f$ is constant.
